# Which weapons count for "5 kills with stationary weapons" pin?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I've have had something like 12 kills in a round with VADS, still didn't get the pin. So which weapons do count for this pin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the EA website, the following weapons are categorized as Stationary:

- Heavy MG X312
- Heavy MG Kord
- Stationary AT Korn
- Anti-Ait Gun ZU23

As they are not really up to date on their websites as always, expansions may add other weapons to the list.

[image: Stationary weapons]

Comment: awkward, this list doesn't include TOW, XM307, QLZ8 nor VADS

Comment: @vartec I also found the list quite small but it's what is displayed on the EA website. Anyway, as I said, they are not really recognized for having their websites up-to-date...

Answer (score 2):

I gained this pin achievement and other pin related achievements by using the mounted MGs -- particularly, especially the shielded MG next to objective B in Nelson Bay.

It great to  cover all enemy's approaches, resulting in a high numbers of kills.